# Huge data being fetch using Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, orm, criteria

I have a problems when fetching the data's from my Database it's about 6 million records. This is a web app and then tomcat log returns GC Limit exceeded.

other solutions is that pagination then every page we query.

Maybe there are some other techniques/workaround for this.

It has 2 Joint Columns which are also objects.

```
public class PricesRaw {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "price_raw_id")
private int price_raw_id;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "year")
private int year;

@Column(name = "size")
private int size;

@Column(name = "stock")
private int stock;

@Column(name = "price")
private double price;

@Column(name = "idccy")
private int ccy;

@Column(name = "status")
private int status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idwine")
private Wine wine;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idmerchant")
private Merchant merchant;

public PricesRaw(){}

public PricesRaw(Date date, int year, int size, int stock, Double price,
                 int idccy, int status, Wine idWine, Merchant idMerchant)
{
    this.date = date;
    this.year = year;
    this.size = size;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.price = price;
    this.ccy = idccy;
    this.status = status;
    this.wine = idWine;
    this.merchant = idMerchant;
}   

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getCcy() {
    return ccy;
}

public void setCcy(int ccy) {
    this.ccy = ccy;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Wine getWine() {
    return wine;
}

public void setWine(Wine wine) {
    this.wine = wine;
}

public Merchant getMerchant() {
    return merchant;
}

public void setMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
    this.merchant = merchant;
}
```

}
This is my hibernate being called. I'm new to Hibernate still exploring it's capabilities any techniques would be much appreciated

```
    public List<PricesRaw> getPrices()
{
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PricesRaw.class);
    // Problem is here. 
    return (List<PricesRaw>) criteria.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Saul we face this kind of problem in real time applications. But as far as the techniques are concerned we have two ways to get it done.

1. **Lazy loading** **/** **Pagination**
2. **Eager loading**

### **Lazy loading**

To achieve lazy loading use below code.

```
 public List<PricesRaw> getPrices() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(PricesRaw.class);
    criteria.setFirstResult(first);
    criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    return (List<PricesRaw>) criteria.list();
}
```

This way you can save yourself from `GC Limit exceeded` as well as out of memory in tomcat.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I can visualize your idea. Could you explain it much further of what you mean about first & pageSize? thanks for the reply.

Comment: Its actually your page lower and upper limit. Let say if you wanna display first 10 records so `first = 1` and `pageSize = 10`.